# Mass inertia tensor for rod non-symmetric regarding coordinate system origin

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, inertia-matrix

I want to express the inertia tensor of a rotating rod (total length $L_1$) to use it in Lagrange mechanics for expressing the kinetic energy associated to the rotation with angular velocity $\dot{\theta}_1$. I know the moment of inertia regarding the center of mass $m_1$ as $1/12\cdot m_1 L_1^2$ and with the central axes theorem I obtain
$$
J_{1yy} = J_{1zz} = 1/12\cdot m_1 L_1^2 + m_1 l_{c,1}^2
$$
So I can express the the kinetic energy as
$$
1/2 \cdot \dot{\theta}_1^2 (1/12\cdot m_1 L_1^2 + m_1 l_{c,1}^2)
$$
Is that right?

The rotation is constrained to the horizontal plane around the origin ($\vec{x}_i = \vec{0}$)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. Using parallel axis theorem, you add the moment of inertia by $m*r^2$

Sometimes they use$ \ \omega^2 \ for \ \dot \theta^2  $ as angular velocity. But it is in a context where the need to convert quantities to linear velocity$.